# Converting image to imagedata and vice versa without drawing to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm wondering if there's a way to convert images to `imagedata` and vice versa without drawing to canvas.

I know the methods `getImageData()` and `toDataURL()` can be used to copy the canvas but what if I'd prefer to take an `imc.src` path and convert that directly to `imagedata`. Or convert `imagedata` directly to a `DataURL` without passing it to canvas.

Comment: Why not just render it off-screen?

Comment: I think that's that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to this question is no. If you check out the [docs for ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData), you'll see that it's tied quite directly to the canvas element and all it's properties are read-only. In addition, if you pop into the console and try `new ImageData`, you'll see that it's not allowed for you to construct one from scratch yourself, and that the function contents are native code.

If someone finds a way to do this, I'd be very impressed -- you never know what you don't know. But since the spec specifically says it shouldn't be possible and clearly efforts have been made to prevent it from happening, I'd say it's probably not a good bet either way.

Perhaps there's another workaround for the issue you are facing. If you re-word your question to include a more broad view of your problem, some of us might be able to suggest possible alternate solutions, as you are starting to see in the first comment.

Comment: Thanks for such a speedy reply. I know that new ImageData objects can be created with the method createImageData(). I have also seen code where ImageData.data is set to a variable then that var is modified and passed back but after taking a second look I see that a virtual canvas was set up. It's is possible to do what I ask using virtual canvas's?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are using a canvas, you can interact with ImageData without issue. You can use an offscreen or hidden canvas to do this if you don't want it to show for the user, but you must be using canvas.